# Meta_query is not working on Elementor Custom Query Filter

Tags: custom-field

I’m following [this tutorial](https://developers.elementor.com/custom-query-filter/) to create a custom query filter.

I would like to filter by a metadata created by ACF (Advanced Custom Field), but it seems not working for me.

My code is like this:

```
add_action('elementor_pro/posts/query/my_custom_qurery', function($query) {
    $searchStr = get_search_query();

    $meta_query = [
        'key' => 'codigo_de_barra',
        'value' => $searchStr,
        'compare' => '=',
    ];

    $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
    $query->set('post_type', 'produto');
});
```

I’m using the widget “Posts” to display the results and I’m sure that I have set the custom query to Custom ID field, because the post_type is affecting results when I change it.

Why meta_query is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meta query is an array containing arrays and not only one array (you can set multiple queries). So it should be:

```
$meta_query = [ [
    'key' => 'codigo_de_barra',
    'value' => $searchStr,
    'compare' => '=',
] ];
```

Comment: God! You just hit the nail on the head! It's working now, I spent hours trying to fix this, thank you very much!

Comment: Done! Thank you so much